# Why do DC motor controllers have minimum voltage?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, h-bridge

I'm trying to build an H bridge to rapidly toggle between a variable voltage from 0 to ±30v.

When I look online for pre-built motor controllers, the lowest voltage they go is around 1v.

This is strange because when I look at a simple four chip MOSFET H bridge design, I don't see any reason why there should be a lower limit on the voltage that actually hits the motor?  I understand there needs to be a minimal voltage to activate the MOSFET.

Sample spec sheet:
[image: arduino motor shield]

[Here is another one that goes from 5v to 12v](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino_MotorShield_Rev3-schematic.pdf).

What I expect the circuit to contain:
[image: Simulation]

Four of these chips ([863-NDDL01N60Z-1G](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/NDDL01N60Z-D-1022936.pdf)) should be able to achieve a similar effect, but lets you get low voltage across the "motor" terminal?

Why can't these shields output a small voltage across the motor? For example, 0.2v?

Comment: Google Vgs(th) - aka gate threshold voltage. Also remember that the Falstad simulator is not an accurate simulation tool, the devices in it do not mimic real world devices.

Comment: WHat exactly do you mean the lowest they go is 1V?

Comment: They are usually PWM, are you sure that's not the minimum motor voltage they will work at. If so, 1V motors are pretty rare.

Comment: Please post a link to the schematic for the motor driver.  (If this one doesn't come with a schematic, than find one that does.)

Comment: @TomCarpenter Actually it has a user adjustable threshold voltage, although I am sure what that threshold has to do with the circuit.

Comment: @Mikhail yes, it does have a box that allows you to enter a number, that in no way makes it accurate.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Okay, maybe I'm missing something about what this has to do with the issue of minimum voltage through the motor?

Comment: FETs take a certain gate voltage to turn on. Almost all generic H-Bridge circuits you can buy derive the gate voltage from the motor voltage in some way. As such, when the motor voltage is insufficient to turn on the MOSFETs, they stop working. There is no reason you couldn't design a H-Bridge that works down to arbitrarily low voltages, but it's not a commonly needed thing, so it's not trivially available.

Comment: "Why can't these shields output a small voltage? Like 0.2v?" - they _can_, with PWM. But not many devices are designed to work on a power supply voltage of 0.2V, and not many motors either.

Comment: @BruceAbbott For some applications, like controlling fancy electro-optical devices, PWMs aren't the same thing as actual voltage levels. I think the specific chip can't do under 5V  because its feeding into some kind of TTL device. But I'm not sure.

Comment: If your 'motor' isn't happy with PWM voltage control then you shouldn't be using a PWM controller! You may be right about the specific driver chips needing 5V, but since the controller has all N-MOSFETs it _could_ have been designed to work down to 0V motor supply voltage. It probably wasn't simply because the designers didn't think it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any reason why there should be a lower limit on the
>   voltage that actually hits the motor?

Without a schematic it's difficult to say, but that board appears to derive its driver supply voltage from the motor supply via a step-down switching regulator, which sets the minimum input voltage. The FETs themselves would probably be quite happy to operate down to 0V, provided they got sufficient Gate drive.

All active components need some minimum voltage to drive them (2.5V for a typical low voltage power MOSFET, 0.6V for a bipolar silicon transistor etc.). If the supply voltage is lower then it can be boosted, but the booster circuit must still be able to work on the lower voltage!

Alternatively the controller could have a separate driver/logic supply voltage input, then the motor supply voltage need not be a limitation.

So the reason your controller has a lower limit on motor supply voltage is simply that it was a design decision to not use a separate supply. Since the Arduino runs on 5V, they *could* have used that to power the drivers, but chose not to. This probably also applies to motor controllers that operate down to 1V, since they are designed to work from a single supply.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not so much the H bridge itself as driving the H bridge.

The N mosfets are relatively easy. They are tied to ground so you can just feed logic signals into them directly.

The P mosfets are where it gets tricky. Their control signals must be relative to the motor supply voltage. To turn them off the control signal must be close to or greater than the motor supply voltage while to turn them on the control signal must be significantly less than the motor supply voltage.

So the control signal you need for the P mosfets is heavily dependent on the motor supply voltage.

If the motor supply voltage is very low then you need a *Negative* gate drive signal to properly turn on the P-Fets.

If the motor supply voltage is sufficiently high to properly turn on the fets but less than or approximately equal to your logic voltage you can drive the P-Fets directly from your logic.

If the motor supply voltage is significantly higher than your logic voltage then you will need a signal of significatly higher voltage than your normal logic supply to properly turn off the P-Fets.

Motor controller chips are generally designed to operate in the third region.